# Criar e manter um loadbar enquanto uma função é chamada

Tags: angularjs, html5

Preciso criar um *loadbar* e deixa-lo ativo até a função terminar. Consigo fazer isso no angular?

```
$scope.getPosts = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/getPosts',
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: Como assim um loader?

Comment: @FelipeDuarte, um Loadbar.

Comment: Já respondi algo parecido, em vez de intercalar em cada rota, basta intercalar na chamada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/225936/qual-a-melhor-forma-de-implementar-um-loading-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

Basicamente você vai controlar o "loader" usando a diretiva **`ng-if`**.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('mainController', mainController);

function mainController($http) {
  let ctrl = this;
  ctrl.loading = false;

  ctrl.iniciar = () => ctrl.loading = true;
  ctrl.parar = () => ctrl.loading = false;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController as main">
  <div ng-if="main.loading">
    Carregando <br>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="main.iniciar()">Iniciar</button>  
  <button ng-click="main.parar()">Parar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Poderia mostrar um exemplo em que apenas com o clique de botão o loader aparece?

Comment: @AntonioBrazFinizola Pronto