# Como criar um sistema de loading nas páginas do site

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como abrir uma contagem em % durante o carregamento do site ao abrir e ao navegar pelas páginas `exemplo: carregando 50%` assim para todas as páginas do site, inclusive ao abrir

Comment: E o que já tentou fazer? Qual foi a dificuldade encontrada?

Comment: Na verdade não fiz nada, não sei por onde começar

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40822/5878

Comment: Até sei de uma forma de fazer isso, mas seria uma trabalheira muito grande, não seria nada prático e nada SEO-friendly: seria carregar praticamente o site inteiro via websocket dividindo-o em pacotes de dados a serem contabilizados enquanto tudo está sendo carregado.

Answer (score -1):

Já existe uma postagem parecida neste fórum, segue o link:

[Como obter porcentagem de carregamento de página?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40822/como-obter-porcentagem-de-carregamento-de-p%C3%A1gina)

Basicamente não é possível fazer isso que você está querendo, mas dependendo do caso, é citado dois exemplos (não recomendados) que podem ser usados.

Segue o link dos dois exemplos:

http://0.s3.envato.com/files/2526201/index.html

http://jsfiddle.net/Edultra/5NCxX/1/

Boa sorte.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/135279)

Comment: @Dvdsamm Acabei de editar a resposta, obrigado pela dica.